# How do I make a nextjs middleware that checks to see if an authenticated user is an admin?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I'm essentially trying to build a next middleware that checks if a logged in firebase user is an admin. The problem is that I can't get a firebase authenticated user in `src/middleware.ts`

**Code**

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
import { onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './firebase';

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if(request.url.includes('/admin')) {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  }
  // return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
}
```

The `console.log(user)` outputs `null`. If I change the console to `console.log(auth);` I get `currentUser: null,`.

I know the user is logged in because I can use the same firebase function to retrieve the user with an `onClick`. For example this works:

```
const GetUser = () => {
  const buttonClick = async () => {
    await onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log(user);
    });
  }

  return (<button onClick={buttonClick}>Get Logged in user</button>)
}
```

How do I get a firebase authenticated user in a next middleware?